# Collect powers of variables and integers separately?

Tags: polynomials, algebraic-manipulation, expression-manipulation

Let `expr` contain a sum of powers of `x` with some coefficients `ci`. The exponents of `x` can contain variables and/or integers. I would like to define a function `MyCollect` in *Mathematica* which would first collect all powers containing variables and would then collect all powers containing integers within the first collection. For example, such that if:

```
expr = c0 x^(a+b)+c1 x^(a+b+1)+c2 x^(a+b+2)+c3 x^(a+b+2)+c4 x^(a+b+2)+c5 x^(a)+c6 x^(a+1)+c7 x^(a+1)
```

the result would be:

```
MyCollect[expr]
```

> ```
> x^(a)(c5 + x(c6+c7)) + x^(a+b)(c0 + x c1 + x^2(c2 + c3 + c4))
> ```

Is there a convenient way to do this? Thanks for any suggestion!

**EDIT**

Here is a second, more complicated example

```
expr = c0 x^(a+b)+c1 x^(a+b+1)+c2 x^(a+b+2)+c3 x^(2a+b+2)+c4 x^(a+b+2)+c5 x^(a)+c6 x^(a+1)+c7 x^(a+1)+c8 x^(a+c+1)+c9 x^(a+c)
```

Desired output of `MyCollect[expr]`:

> ```
> x^(a)(c5 +x(c6+c7)) + x^(a+b)(c0 +x c1+x^2(c2+c4)) + x^(2a+b)(x^2 c3) + x^(a+c)(c9+x c8)
> ```

All unique combinations of powers involving variables are collected first, and then the remaining integer powers are collected at a second level, so to say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Update:* This matches the evaluated form of your desired output for each example:

```
fn = Collect[#, x^y_ /; FreeQ[y, _Integer], Apart] &;
```

Test:

```
expr1 = c0 x^(a + b) + c1 x^(a + b + 1) + c2 x^(a + b + 2) + c3 x^(a + b + 2) + 
   c4 x^(a + b + 2) + c5 x^(a) + c6 x^(a + 1) + c7 x^(a + 1);

target1 = x^(a) (c5 + x (c6 + c7)) + x^(a + b) (c0 + x c1 + x^2 (c2 + c3 + c4));


expr2 = c0 x^(a + b) + c1 x^(a + b + 1) + c2 x^(a + b + 2) + c3 x^(2 a + b + 2) + 
   c4 x^(a + b + 2) + c5 x^(a) + c6 x^(a + 1) + c7 x^(a + 1) + c8 x^(a + c + 1) + 
   c9 x^(a + c);

target2 = x^(a) (c5 + x (c6 + c7)) + x^(a + b) (c0 + x c1 + x^2 (c2 + c4)) + 
   x^(2 a + b) (x^2 c3) + x^(a + c) (c9 + x c8);

fn[expr1]

fn[expr2]

fn[expr1] === target1

fn[expr2] === target2
```

> ```
> x^a (c5 + (c6 + c7) x) + x^(a + b) (c0 + c1 x + (c2 + c3 + c4) x^2)
>
> c3 x^(2 + 2 a + b) + x^a (c5 + (c6 + c7) x) + x^(a + c) (c9 + c8 x) + 
>  x^(a + b) (c0 + c1 x + (c2 + c4) x^2)
>
> True
>
> True
> ```

Comment: Yes, it seems to do the right thing at least for the short example above. I'll have to test if it will still work accordingly in more complicated cases. But I see no reason why it should not.

Comment: I just wonder what the syntax `/@` means?

Comment: Now I tried a slightly more complicated example and unfortunately the result was not correct. See my edit above.

Comment: @Kagaratsch Please include the desired output for the second example.

Comment: /@ is a short for map[],you can search it in the "Help" document of Mathematic

Comment: Wow! Thank you, this looks promising. Now I only hope that it will also work as intended for the actually meaningful data I get.

Comment: @Kagaratsch Thanks for the Accept.  Let me know if you have any problems with this code.